# How to access key from python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to access key 'Description' from dict below?

```
{text:u'Description': u'ABC',text:u'Balance': u'35,402,678.51',text:u'Credit': u'10,000.00'}
```

Tried using `mydict.get('Description')` & `mydict['Description']`. please provide your suggestions, i am new to python.

Comment: my suggestion would be to read [Beginning Programming Python](http://thepythonguru.com/)

Comment: Did you try to type in Google `python dict get keys`?

Comment: The official [Tutorial in the Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) should be a good starting point. This will help you create a valid data structure - your "dict" is not valid Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the solution. error was due to "text" prefix. eliminated it using (myxlrdcell).value

Answer (score 0):

In your example, all your keys have a strange `text:` prefix, that result in an invalid dictionary (or rather in invalid syntax).

Otherwise your attempts are correct:

```
mydict = {u'Description': u'ABC',
u'Balance': u'35,402,678.51',
u'Credit': u'10,000.00'}

v = mydict.get('Description')

print(v) # ABC
```

By the way, if you get an error, you should add the complete traceback to your question, this will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: There's nothing strange about `unicode`.

Comment: @kabanus I'm not talking about ``u``, I'm talking about ``text:u``, which (at least in my Python 3) is invalid syntax.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think it's an IDE thing, and he just pasted from my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

“text:” is redundant, it can be left out.

dic = {u'Description': u'ABC', u'Balance': u'35,402,678.51', u'Credit': u'10,000.00'}